# Как вращать изображение, пока функция не вернула значение?

Tags: javafx

Не понимаю, как сделать условие "пока сервер не вернул значение, вращать картинку". И также хотелось бы узнать как просто вращать картинку, а не через `setAngle`.

Как должно работать:
В моём приложении пользователь вводит логин и пароль, после этого отправляется запрос в базу данных. Пока сервер не подтвердил, что такой пользователь есть, должна проигрываться анимация синхронизации (вращение картинки). Как только сервер вернул `true` или `false`, анимация должна закончится.

Как работает сейчас:
После ввода логина и пароля проигрывается анимация, но сервер отвечает почти мгновенно, и получив ответ от сервера, картинка всё ещё вращается.

```
RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(2.5), synchronize);

rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);

rotateTransition.setToAngle(720);

rotateTransition.play();
```

`synchronize` - это `ImageView`

Comment: Ну так вам надо сделать rotateTransition.stop(). Вы это делаете в своем коде?

Comment: Да, я пробовал делать rotateTransition.stop(), но дело в том, что у меня картинка поворачивается на 720 градусов, то есть совершает 2 оборота, а если ответ от сервера будет больше чем 2.5 секунды, то картинка дальше вращаться на будет.

Comment: Можно ли вращать картинку другим способом? Грубо говоря вращать её бесконечно, пока функция не вернула значение, а потом просто сделать rotateTransition.stop()